# Blogger redirect happens after the full page loads first?

Tags: blogger, redirect

I am using a meta tag to redirect my Blogger page, however the redirect happens after the old Blogger then the redirect happens.

Is there any way to redirect **without** loading the old Blogger page completely first?

I am using the following code in the header section of my template:

```
<meta content='0;URL=&apos;http://newsite.com' http-equiv='refresh'/>
```

Comment: The position of the meta tag matters , try adding it just after starting head tag in the template and then you should see considerable difference

Answer (score 1):

You should place your redirect code right after opening the head tag. This kind of [**JS redirect code**](http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/) generator will help you with this kind of situations. You should not use plain `HTML meta` redirect, but this all-in-one solution:

```
<!-- Pleace this snippet right after opening the head tag to make it work properly -->

<!-- This code is licensed under GNU GPL v3 -->
<!-- You are allowed to freely copy, distribute and use this code, but removing author credit is strictly prohibited -->
<!-- Generated by http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/ -->

<!-- REDIRECTING STARTS -->
<link rel="canonical" href="http://newsite.com"/>
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://newsite.com">
</noscript>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript">var IE_fix=true;</script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "http://newsite.com";
    if(typeof IE_fix != "undefined") // IE8 and lower fix to pass the http referer
    {
        document.write("redirecting..."); // Don't remove this line or appendChild() will fail because it is called before document.onload to make the redirect as fast as possible. Nobody will see this text, it is only a tech fix.
        var referLink = document.createElement("a");
        referLink.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(referLink);
        referLink.click();
    }
    else { window.location.replace(url); } // All other browsers
</script>
<!-- Credit goes to http://insider.zone/ -->
<!-- REDIRECTING ENDS -->
```

It has search engine support, compatible with all browsers, and it avoids redirecting loops.